# How to use RouteData in Angular2 Beta?

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

I'm facing problems when I try to use `RouteData` in Angular2 Beta using TypeScript.

I inject it in the constructor and import it properly

```
import {RouteConfig, Router, RouteData} from 'angular2/router';

export class App {
    constructor(public router: Router, public data: RouteData) {
        // router works - routedata not
    }
}
```

I'm getting `No provider for RouteData! (App -> RouteData)`.

If I include it into the component annotation like this

```
@Component({
  //..
  providers: [RouteData]
})
```

I get this error: `Cannot resolve all parameters for RouteData(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.`

Comment: Don't inject `RouteData` through providers yourself. Angular2 does all that for you.

Comment: You mean importing `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`? How can I get typescript compile then?

Comment: [`ROUTER_PROVIDERS`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/router.ts#L84) doesn't provide `RouteData` nor `RouteParams`, therefore they're not available in the root component. They are provided by [`RouterOulet`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/router_outlet.ts#L60), so they will be available in any component loaded through routing.

Comment: So I can't access the data in `App` itself only in below components? (Please correct me if I'm missunderstanding - I'm new to ng2) My aim is to make some kind of navbar outside the routeroutlet disappear depending on the routing. So I tried to do it with ngif using a boolean of the routedata.

Comment: Exactly. But it's not only your `App` component, it's any component that is NOT loaded through routing.

Comment: @EricMartinez Ok thank you so far. Could you make any suggestions regarding the navbar thing? Different approach maybe? Thanks.

Comment: You can subscribe to `Router` in the root component (yes, you can inject Router in it). When you subscribe to it you'll have access to the current URL, that can help you.

Comment: Hm ok. Checking the URL was something I wanted to avoid. But it should work this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

RouteData provides data to your child component by the RouteConfig in your parent component.
There shouldn't be any need to use it in your AppComponent.

To use it you should provide a RouteConfig in your AppComponent like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/child', name: 'Child', component: ChildCmp, data: {item: 'hi there'}}
])
```

Your ChildComponent should then inject RouteData and is able to retrieve the parameter set in the route like this:

```
export class ChildCmp {
  constructor(@Inject(RouteData) private data:RouteData) {
    this.data.get("item")
  }
}
```